# trigger email one day before due date using javascript

Tags: javascript, servicenow

i need to send email to assignee 1 day before the due date. I have this code but this sending emails to all records not to the the which is due tomorrow.

```
while(gr.next()) {
    var u_loaner_return_date = gr.getValue("u_loaner_return_date");
    var today_date = gs.daysAgo(1);
    if(u_loaner_return_date > today_date) {
        gs.eventQueue('Asset_Loaner_Email_BeforeDueDate', gs, gs.getUserID());
    }
}
```

Email should trigger only for those records in which end date is tomorrow.

Comment: what is `gr`, `gs` ... ?

Comment: I work in servicenow development and these are used there. If you can help me with javascript code which will help me trigger email 1 day before due date, that would be great.

Comment: @ATripathi maybe look into Scheduled Jobs or ask this question on the developer website for SNOW

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to create a **Scheduled Job** that, when executed, finds records with a due date within the next 24 hours and triggers an event that sends a notification.

The script below finds all records on the task table with a due date between 24 hours from now and 24 hours and 15 minutes from now. The query would look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7tcq.png). For each found record it will trigger an event, and pass the record itself, and the `assigned_to` as parameters. The scheduled job is set to run once every 15 minutes.

Feel free to manipulate the following script to your liking and add it to the script field of the scheduled job.

```
var gr = new GlideRecord('task');
gr.addEncodedQuery('due_dateRELATIVEGE@minute@ahead@1440^due_dateRELATIVELT@minute@ahead@1555');
gr.query();

while (gr.next()) {

    gs.eventQueue('due_date.approaching.event', gr, gr.assigned_to);

}
```

**Notes:**

When creating a the job on the `sysauto` table, you'll need to selcet "Automatically run a script of your choosing" if you are prompted to do so.

The query string for the addEncodedQuery() function can be obtained by using the filter in a list view of the table you are querying. After choosing your filters, run the filter. On the last query, [right click and select "Copy query"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPrCB.png).

Answer (score 0):

`gr.getValue` and `gs.daysAgo` both return strings, so the comparison you're doing in `if(u_loaner_return_date > today_date)` is just comparing two strings.

What you really want is to compare 2 dates, or use an API that compares the string values as dates. An quick change is to use the ServiceNow API `gs.dateDiff(startDate, endDate, returnNumericSeconds)`:

```
if (gs.dateDiff(u_loaner_return_date, today_date, true) < 0)
    //...u_loaner_return_date is after today_date ...
```

If you need more specific logic (which I think you probably do if you want to know if you're specifically 1 day before and not just *any* day before), the return value of `gs.dateDiff` when you add `true` as the third argument is the difference in seconds, positive if first arg is before second arg, and negative otherwise.